# what does this C++ code to create a triangle mean?

Tags: c++

What does this c++ code mean?

i am trying to figure out what this code means but being new to programming iv not had much luck. This is code to create an equilateral triangle.

```
static const float COS_60 = 0.5f;
static const float COS_30 = 0.5f * sqrt(3.f);

const float side = radius * 2.f * COS_30;
const float bottomHeight = point.getY() - COS_60 * radius;


this->vertices.push_back(Vertex(point.getX(), point.getY() + radius));
this->vertices.push_back(Vertex(point.getX() + COS_60 * side, bottomHeight));
this->vertices.push_back(Vertex(point.getX() - COS_60 * side, bottomHeight));
```

Comment: Could you clarify which part it is that you don't understand? The math, adding items to a vector, or?

Comment: the math mainly @MatsPetersson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A equilateral triangle has three sides of equal length. The angle (on the inside) of the corners is 60 degrees, hence needing COS_60. It just so happens that COS 60 = 0.5, so the programmer didn't write code to calculate it, but just used this "known value".

The length of the side is `radius * 2.f * COS_30` (that is the distance from the center to the furthest corner times cosine of 30 degrees). COS_30 happens to be `sqrt(3)/2` or `0.5f * sqrt(3.f)`. Again, you can calculate this, using for example a calculator instead of writing it out as 0.5 * sqrt(3). Or if you want to use C++ functions, you could use `sin(30.0f * 2.f * pi / 180.0f)` [this is because math on computers is, nearly always, done in radians, rather than degrees].

The distance from the bottom to the center is `COS_60 * radius` (half the radius).

If we manually apply this math, given a X, Y center of 400, 400 and a radius of 100, we get:

```
side = 100 * 2 * COS_30 => 200*0.866 = 173;
bottomheight = 400 - COS_60 * radius = 400 - 50 = 350
```

and then the following coordinate:

```
400, (400 + radius)    => 400, 500
400 + COS_60 * side, 350    => 400 + 173 * 0.5, 350 => 486, 350 
400 - COS_60 * side, 350    => 400 - 173 * 0.5, 350 => 314, 350
```

Comment: In this context, it means that the value is a `float`, where the compiler will by default treat floting point constants as `double`. Particularly when doing 3D graphics and similar, programmers tend to use `float` rather than `double` because it uses less space.